# Question solving tensor problems for the Special Conformal Killing Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, tensor-calculus, conformal-field-theory

**Background**

I know that following index notation, these are true:

$$\partial_\mu x^\nu = \delta^\mu _\nu \hspace{5mm} and \hspace{5mm} \partial_\mu x_\nu = \eta_{\mu\nu} \tag{1}$$

**Exercise**

Knowing that:

$$K_{i\nu} = x^2_i \partial_{i\nu} -2x_{i\nu} x^\mu_i \partial_{i\mu} \tag{2}$$

*where $i=1,2$*.

I must show:

$$(K_{1\nu}+ K_{2\nu}) x^2_{12}= -2(x_{1\nu} + x_{2\nu})x^2_{12}\tag{3}$$

where:

$$x^2_{12}= (x_1 -x_2)^\mu (x_1 - x_2)_\mu \tag{4}$$

**Question and my take on it**

Based on the background above,and expanding equation (4),  when trying to do equation (3) I am not sure of some of the rules, for example, doing a small part of the question:

$$K_{1\nu}x^2_{12}=  x^2_1 \partial_{1\nu}(x^\mu_1 x_{1\mu}-x^\mu_1 x_{2\mu} - x^\mu _2 x_{1\mu}+x^\mu_2 x_{2\mu}) -2x_{1\nu} x^\mu_1\partial_{1\mu}((x^\mu_1 x_{1\mu}-x^\mu_1 x_{2\mu} - x^\mu _2 x_{1\mu}+x^\mu_2 x_{2\mu}))$$

When differentiating the first half I come across terms like:

$$\partial_{1\nu}(x^\mu_1x_{1\mu})= x^\mu_1(\partial_{1\nu}x_{1\mu})+ (\partial_{1\nu}x^\mu _1)x_{1\mu}$$

**To do these equations, do they follow the equations (1) and become?:**

$$\partial_{1\nu}x_{1\mu}= \eta_{1\nu 1\mu} \hspace{5mm} and  \hspace{5mm} \partial_{1\nu}x^\mu _1= \delta_{1\nu 1}^{\hspace{2mm} \mu}$$

**Or are these simply equal to zero?**

**And what happens in cases like this?:**

$$\partial_{1\mu}(x_{2\mu})$$

I don't know how to solve the notation when there are numbers $i=1,2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have a typo in your first relation. $\partial_\mu x^\nu = \delta^\nu_\mu$ and not $\delta^\mu_\nu$. Now, $i=1,2$ is telling you to differentiate with respect to $x_i$. Some bracketing might help to see it more clearly. It is
$$(\partial_i)_\mu (x_j)^\nu = \frac{\partial}{\partial (x_i)^\mu} (x_j)^\nu = \delta_{ij}\delta^\nu_\mu.$$

The rest should follow:
$$(\partial_1)_\nu (x_1)_\mu = \eta_{\nu\mu} \qquad (\partial_1)_\mu (x_1)^\mu = \delta^\nu_\mu$$
It doesn't make sense to put 1 and 2 in $\eta$ and $\delta$; $i$ is simply there to ask the question "Is it the first guy I'm talking about or the second?".

Finally
$$(\partial_1)_\mu (x_{12})^2 = (\partial_1)_\mu (x_1-x_2)_\nu(x_1-x_2)^\nu = 2(x_1-x_2)_\nu\, \delta^\nu_\mu = 2(x_1-x_2)_\mu,$$
while similarly
$$(\partial_2)_\mu (x_{12})^2 = -2(x_1-x_2)_\mu.$$

It's simply a matter of composing the steps to get the equation you're looking for from here on.

Comment: On your first equation, you initially placed an $i$ in $(x_i)^\nu$ and followed it by $(x_j)^\nu$. Is that a typo? Or was it meant to be like that and I just don't quite get it.

Thank you for telling me about my typo

Comment: Yes it was a typo, sorry for that. Corrected!

Comment: In your second equation, did you do differentiation by parts? I was trying to replicate it, but all I got to was (by considering $x_1 -x_2$ to be a single number, like $y$. 

$$(x_1 -x_2)_\nu (\partial_1)_\mu (x_1-x_2)^\nu + (\partial_1)_\mu(x_1-x_2)_\nu)(x_1-x_2)^\nu$$

$$(x_1-x_2)_\nu \delta^\nu _\mu + \eta_{\mu\nu}(x_1-x_2)^\nu$$

But this isn't the same that you got.

Comment: Well it actually is. Generally $a_\nu\delta^\nu_\mu = a_\mu$ and $\eta_{\mu\nu}b^\nu = b_\mu$ for whatever $a$ and $b$, by definition of the Kronecker delta and of the metric tensor. So your last expression evaluates simply to $2(x_1-x_2)_\mu$.

Comment: Of course, I was being silly, and must have misplaced the tensors on paper. Thank you